# Java multi thread problem .join()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have checked different questions in this and in other forums, but I didn't find the solution to my problem.

I have an application which runs `ffmpeg` and `exiftool` processes. I have concurrency probles, and I would like to control them, using `Thread`. This is how I built it:

**ExiftoolThread**

```
public class ExiftoolThread extends Thread{

    String file;

    public ExiftoolThread(String file){
        this.file = file;
    }
     public void run(){
                serviceToExiftool(file);//Create metadata file
    }
}
```

**FfmpegThread**

```
public class FfmpegThread extends Thread{

    String itemName;

    public FfmpegThread(String itemName){
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
     public void run(){
         serviceFFmpeg(itemName);//Create thumbnai froma  video
    }
}
```

Main call

```
Thread exiftoolThread = new ExiftoolThread(file.getName());
        exiftoolThread.run();
        try {
            exiftoolThread.join(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.write("JSON file created.It contains the metadata. ");


            Thread ffmpegThread = new FfmpegThread(itemName);
            ffmpegThread.run();
            try {
                ffmpegThread.join(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.write("Thumbnail created successfully. ");
```

After this call finishes, there are more actions working with the results of these processes, and there is always one of them which is missed. I guess that's because one of them (exiftool or ffmpeg) finishes earlier and then the process continue before the other finishes.

I am using  `ffmpegThread.join(3000);` to skip this problem, as the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) says, this method waits untill the thread is died. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answers are correct about `start()` instead of `run()`, but it seems to be really pointless to start a thread only to join it immediately. What is it that you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: the thread starts, makes the function in the method run(), creates a file (using ffmpeg or exiftool) and then, when these actions are finished, I want to continue the normal actions. As the suggestion below, I wrote join() at the end

Comment: But what do you get out of this that you wouldn't get from simply doing the same actions in the original thread? If you're keeping the original thread blocked for _the entire time_ the subtread does anything, you might just as well use the original thread.

Comment: I don't want to use the original thread, in order to controll the concurrency between exiftool and ffmpeg

Comment: The problem I was facing was tha maybe ffmpeg finished first, and the main process continue without waiting for exiftool. Then, there were more actions which needed the result from exiftool and they couldnt', because that process was not finished yet.
Then I think that thebest option is to manage in this way. DO you have a better idea?? Thanks for your answers

Comment: In your code, ffmpeg isn't even started before exiftool has already finished. Again, if you _want_ them to run at the same time, you should accept the answer that tells you how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `start()` to run the code in the new thread. Also, `join()` block the current thread, so you have to call it after you start all your thread.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `Thread.start()` instead of `Thread.run()` on your two threads. The `start()` method actually spins a new thread to execute code concurrently, while the `run()` method is a normal method that executes in the calling thread like any other.

additionally, you can improve your thread synchronization setup by replacing the `join()` calls by use of a `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`. Your main code will look like this:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
Thread ffmpegThread = new FfmpegThread(itemName, latch);
Thread exifToolThread = new ExifToolThread(itemName, latch);
ffmpegThread.start();
exifToolThread.start();

latch.await(); // With optional timeout
```

Your two helper threads must both call `latch.countDown()` when they're done.